# make static buttons dynamic

Tags: iphone

I have added 10 custom buttons using interface on view. Now I want to make visible that no of buttons only whenever user put value. e.g If user put 5 then on button click 5 buttons get visible. Can it be possible? If anyone know please give me the solution.

Thanks alot.

Comment: Are you getting the value you are pressing somewhere, like in a uilabel or uitextview?

Comment: It's possible but we will need more than a spec sheet here. What've you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Set Tag for each button in xib. Compare the tag value & show the button.

Answer (score 0):

set tag in increasing order lets say 100+buttonNumber (100,101,102...110).

Now for user's input you would have a UITextField(lets say mtTextField) and a button (lets say "Show") to see the effect.so do following in the tuchUpInside method of Show button

```
int i = [myTextField intValue];
UIButton* btn;
for(int j = 1; j<=i;j++)
{
    btn = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:100+j];
    [btn setHidden:NO];
}
```